# Placing item to its grandparent

Tags: html, css, grid

I am currently in a situation, in which i have a nested div `item2half` that I want to be placed somewhere in my
`grid-container` -  the problem is with where it is located in the html - I am not able to locate it within the `grid-container`
and if I make `item-2` to an grid will `item2half` be placed within the `item-2` position in the `grid-container` grid.

html

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2
    <div class="item2half">
      2.5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item-1 {
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.item-2 {
    background-color: rgba(145,223,0,.75);
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.item-3 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.item-4 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.item2half {
    background-color: rgb(20,100,255);
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}
```

Code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewqmXw

I want `item2half` to be placed in the grid-container column 2 row 1

Comment: Please provide Snippet of what You are getting and also the example image of what you want to achieve

Comment: Added a code pen, basically I want `item2half` above `item1` @muhammad bilal

Answer (score 0):

Like that? I just edited html, and your item2half  is above item1 in column 2 row 1. If that's not what you are asking for, please be more specific.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLvbvR

```
<div class="grid-container">
 <div class="item-1">1</div>
<div class="item-2">2
</div>
<div class="item2half">2.5</div>
<div class="item-3">3</div>
<div class="item-4">4</div>
```

Comment: No 2.5 should be a child of 2

Comment: If you want 2.5 to be a child of 2 then grid-column: 2; and  grid-row: 1; won't do anything because 2.5's parent is not grid displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I've Edited Your Pen And set Item two to be grid, Checkout this Pen if that did help.
[CedePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agevqj)

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="item2full">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="item2half">
      2.5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Css :

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item-1 {
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.item-2 {
    background-color: rgba(145,223,0,.75);
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    grid-row: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    background:transparent;
}

.item-3 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.item-4 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.item2half {
    background-color: rgb(20,100,255);
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.item2full {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}
```

Comment: Will this also work for ie I seem to see something completely different..